# Jython logging gets time wrong

Tags: python, logging, timestamp, jython

I have a Jython script that uses the Python logging module for logging. On one machine the script logs fine and on the other the time logged is shifted five hours into the future. Presumably this has to do with the machine being at GMT-5. What do you think can cause this issue?

Here's how I create the logging object:

```
log = logging.getLogger("my_log")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
        log_file,
        maxBytes=log_size,
        backupCount=logs_count)
log_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(log_format)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(handler)
```

I did look at the `log_format.converter` function. I did make sure the time is set properly on the problematic machine. And I did make sure Python prints the correct time in the Python shell.

**Edit**: If I look at `time.localtime()` from the Python shell (2.4.3) then I get a tuple with correct local time values. If I look at `time.localtime()` from within the Jython script (2.5.2RC1) then I see the time in GMT.

Comment: Does the machine that logs correctly use GMT?

Comment: Yes, it does: it's a Linux machine, and Unix machines use GMT internally and then they do the math. The other machine ... I'm not sure. I mean I know it's CentOS release 5 (Final), judging from /etc/issues, but I think it's virtualized. On both machines when I run `date` from bash I get the correct time.

Comment: I have also tried explicitly setting `log_format.converter=time.localtime` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue. Apparently Java itself was getting the time wrong, and the reason was that the timezone was not set properly for Java on the problematic machine. `export TZ='US/East'` in /etc/profile.d/java.sh seems to solve the issue.

This took me some time to figure out because running `date` from the shell output the correct local time and timezone information. Python too was able to figure out the timezone correctly.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would check where you obtain your timestamp to make sure it is in UTC, and I would check where you hand over the timestamp to make sure that it is actually interpreted by the library as UTC.

Comment: I'm not handing over the time. All the time manipulation is completely hidden inside the logging library. I just specify the format of each log message and then start logging stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What is `log_format.converter` set to? According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#formatters), it defaults to `time.localtime`. If you change it to `time.gmtime`, all times will use GMT.

Comment: I'm not changing it. The code I posted is all I have for setting the logger, apart from getting `log_file`, `log_size` and `logs_count` from elsewhere.